# When reading an XLS file using PHP Excel, how can I detect if a cell is bold?

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel

I have an Excel 2007 xlsx document with "BC/B22--" in cell L2.
It is in bold, and coloured red.
Using PHPExcel (v1.8.0, 2014-03-02) I want to detect whether the cell is bold or not, but I can only get at the value "BC/B22--", and no styling info.

This is my code:

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($sFilepath);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);  
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($sFilepath);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
$cell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11,2);

$v = $cell->getValue();
var_dump($v);
// Echoes: string(8) "BC/B22--" 

$rte = $cell->getValue()->getRichTextElements();
// Error: "Call to a member function getRichTextElements() on a non-object"

echo ($cell->getValue() instanceof PHPExcel_RichText) ? 
    "instance" : "no instance";
// Echoes "no instance"
```

Comment: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/438774

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on whether the cell contains simple text content and bold is set as a cell style, or if the cell content is a rich text object.

If `$cell->getValue()` returns a string, then you need to test the style of the cell:

```
$isBold = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getBold();
```

Otherwise, if `$cell->getValue()` returns a Rich Text Object, then you need to walk that Rich Text object searching to see if any part of it is bolded:

```
$isBold = false;
$elements = $cell->getValue()->getRichTextElements();
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element instanceof PHPExcel_RichText_Run) {
        $isBold |= $element->getFont()->getBold();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It did return a string, and your code sample detects bold.